# Reading c++ window in C# using handler

Tags: c#, c++

I am implementing a plugin for a product called AmiBroker in C#.

AmiBroker is a trading software it has exposed a few functions which can be used by 3rd party vendors to pass the stock data to solution. So, we can create a plugin in C# which can be recognized by AmiBroker.

In my scenario I am getting a handler of Main Window of AmiBroker [Note : AmiBroker is fully written in C++] In C# we can retrieve the handler of Main Window, so using this handle can I read the data of the window e.g. Child windows, Panels showing stock lists or things which are visible to the User, and if so, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you mean iterate through the child windows etc.? Or are you asking whether you can pass the handle to the AmiBroker API?

Comment: Iterating through child windows & reading their data at the same time

Comment: That's going to be very inefficient. You'd be better served by using the API provided.

Comment: At least using Main Handle can I detect whether the child window is active or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but it's messy. I literally just worked on something very similar. Pinvoke.net is great for this stuff, but I'll show you some examples of how I'd find controls. If AmiBroker has any documentation for control names or AccessibleNames or anything that allows you to find the exact controls you're looking for, that'd be killer. Because if they're ambiguously named, you're gonna have a helluva time finding the ones you're specifically looking for. But basically, what you'll want to do is EnumChildWindows on the handle you have, iterate through them and look for a unique property to allow you to find the control you want. Then you'll need to execute a specific SendMessage to get the text off of a control (GetWindowText or whatever it's called only works for labels). Code as follows, adapted or swiped from Pinvoke.net at some point (great starting point):

```
    [DllImport("user32")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumWindowProc callback, IntPtr i);
    public static extern uint GetClassName(IntPtr handle, StringBuilder name, int maxLength);
    public delegate bool EnumWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr parameter);

    private static List<IntPtr> GetChildWindows(IntPtr parent)
    {
        List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();
        GCHandle listHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result);
        try
        {
            EnumWindowProc childProc = new EnumWindowProc(EnumWindow);
            EnumChildWindows(parent, childProc, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(listHandle));
        }
        finally
        {
            if (listHandle.IsAllocated)
                listHandle.Free();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static bool EnumWindow(IntPtr handle, IntPtr pointer)
    {
        GCHandle gch = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(pointer);
        List<IntPtr> list = gch.Target as List<IntPtr>;
        if (list == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException("GCHandle Target could not be cast as List<IntPtr>");
        }
        list.Add(handle);
        //  You can modify this to check to see if you want to cancel the operation, then return a null here
        return true;
    }

    //THIS IS THE ONE YOU'LL CALL!
    public static IntPtr GetWindowByClass(IntPtr mainWindow, string name)
    {
        List<IntPtr> windows = GetChildWindows(mainWindow);
        foreach (IntPtr window in windows)
        {
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            response.Capacity = 500;
            if (GetClassName(window, response, response.Capacity) > 0)
                if (response.ToString() == name)
                    return window;
        }
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

So basically it iterates through a whole set of child windows for the handle you have on the app, sees if the class name matches a control you're looking for, then returns it. There are thousands of ways to improve it (search for all the ones you want in a single shot, FindWindow MAY work by class name, etc.) but I wanted to show you more *how* it's done, not declare this is how it should be done. Finally, the call to get the text from the window/control is as follows (also adapted from pinvoke.net: look under User32.dll for all this stuff):

```
    public static string GetText(IntPtr control)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(40);
        IntPtr result = IntPtr.Zero;
        uint response = SendMessageTimeoutText(control, 0xd, 40, builder, APITypes.SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_NORMAL, 2000, out result);
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageTimeout", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern uint SendMessageTimeoutText(
        IntPtr hWnd,
        int Msg,              // Use WM_GETTEXT
        int countOfChars,
        StringBuilder text,
        APITypes.SendMessageTimeoutFlags flags,
        uint uTImeoutj,
        out IntPtr result);
    [Flags]
    public enum SendMessageTimeoutFlags : uint
    {
        SMTO_NORMAL = 0x0,
        SMTO_BLOCK = 0x1,
        SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x2,
        SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG = 0x8
    }
```

EDIT: An addendum: the application I worked on to access another form like this actually didn't have unique control names, so I ended up using Spy++ to determine its place in the window hierarchy and pulling the children and selecting each child in turn. God help if you have to go that route, especially because it may not be consistent at all, especially if what you need is on a form that isn't created, or it's hidden behind another one that jumped it in the Z-Order (breaking your hierarchical list you're searching from). That said, you should know that EnumChildWindows will always enum ALL CHILD WINDOWS for a given window, no matter where they are in the hierarchy. If you really have to drill down and search for each control by its parent and its parent's parent, you'll need to use FindWindowEx, and declare the last child you looked at (or IntPtr.Zero if you want the first child):

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, string windowTitle);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I never expected this type of answer. I am sure this answer is definitely gonna help me solving my problem.

Comment: Happy to help. I noticed when I was wiring the almost exact same thing up a couple of weeks ago that there was painfully little information available on Stack for doing this stuff; mostly it was "Why on Earth do you event want to?!" So you were very lucky to post this right after I'd just finished doing it. :)

Comment: Yup that's true. Actually it's 11 PM Even i was thinking to post it tomorrow but, something made me post it today that's what we call LUCK

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for seems counter intuitive if the software you are writing the plug-in for provides an API. You should really be using that.

While it is possible to use the Win32 API to enumerate child windows of the main window given the handle and then use more Win32 API functions to determine the state of the UI (i.e. "read the data") it's going to be very tedious and error-prone.

Here's a link to MSDN for [EnumChildWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633494%28VS.85%29.aspx) which will allow you to enumerate child windows for the main window given the handle.

If you want to go down that rabbit hole you might also find [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) useful. And most definitely you should check out [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumchildwindows) if you are going to be using these Win32 APIs from C#.

Comment: Seconded on using the application's API before diving into the world of Windows API calls, but of course mileage varies; you never know if what you need is actually available, and sometimes you just have to go digging into your IntPtr handles...